# Expected value and variance of random variable in n tosses

Tags: random-variables, expected-value

Let $Z$ be the sum of number of tails in odd tosses and number of heads in even tosses. Now I want to calculate expected value. Since $Z=Z_{H}+Z+{T}$, $EZ=EZ_{H}+EZ_{T}$ where $Z_{H}$ is the number of head in odd tosses and $Z_{T}$ is the number of tails in even tosses.
We perform $n$ tosses.
So $$EZ_{H}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}EZ_{Hi}$$ where $Z_{Hi}$ represents random varible for $i$-th toss.
I defined:
$$Z_{Hi}=\begin{cases} 1 \text{ for } i \in Odd \wedge H \text{ (denote it by C1)}
\\ 0 \text{ for } i \notin Odd \wedge H, T \text{ (denote it by C2)}\end{cases} $$

This way we have
$$
EZ_{Hi}=Z_{Hi}(C1)\frac{1}{4}+Z_{Hi}(C2)\frac{3}{4}
$$
It doesn't feel right. What I'm trying to achieve is to have the value dependent on $i$ - whether it is odd or even. I don't know how to express it.

Comment: The index $i$ is not random, so if $i$ is even, then $P(Z_{Hi}=0) = 1$, so 
$E[Z_{Hi}] = 0$. Hence
$$E[Z_{Hi}]= \begin{cases} 0.5 &, \text{ i is odd} \\ 0 &, \text{ i is even}\end{cases}.$$

Comment: Thanks, that explains a lot!

Comment: An alternative and simpler approach is to notice, that it doesn't matter if we count heads, tails or alternate between the two, the probability of succes in each throw will be $1/2$ in any case, and thus the resulting distribution of $Z$ is a $\operatorname{Binomial}(n,1/2)$ distribution.